Flutter I am having problem with Animated Container
I want to show users a horizontal list on the screen. For those who want to examine it in detail, I want to arrange the list elements as a gridview on the screen below, which expands when the button is pressed. I do not have any problems when expanding the screen, but when closing it back, the length of the items changes momentarily.

class HorizontalSection extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<AffirmationAudioBox> items;
  final Widget? leadingContainer;

  const HorizontalSection({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.items,
    this.leadingContainer,
  });

  @override
  State<HorizontalSection> createState() => _HorizontalSectionState();
}

class _HorizontalSectionState extends State<HorizontalSection> {
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white24,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      height: isExpanded ? AppSizes.screenHeight * 37 / 60 : AppSizes.screenHeight * 11 / 60,
      width: AppSizes.screenWidth,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: Paddings.verticalPaddingSmall,
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                child: isExpanded
                    ? GridView.builder(
                        key: ValueKey<bool>(isExpanded),
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          childAspectRatio: 1, 
                        ),
                        itemCount: widget.items.length + (widget.leadingContainer != null ? 1 : 0),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (widget.leadingContainer != null && index == 0) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: widget.leadingContainer!,
                            );
                          }
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child:
                                widget.items[widget.leadingContainer != null ? index - 1 : index],
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : ListView.builder(
                        key: ValueKey<bool>(!isExpanded),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: widget.items.length + (widget.leadingContainer != null ? 1 : 0),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (widget.leadingContainer != null && index == 0) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                              child: widget.leadingContainer!,
                            );
                          }
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: AppSizes.screenHeight / 8, // Consistent width
                              child:
                                  widget.items[widget.leadingContainer != null ? index - 1 : index],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 30,
            width: AppSizes.screenWidth,
            child: Center(
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  isExpanded
                      ? Icons.keyboard_double_arrow_up_outlined
                      : Icons.keyboard_double_arrow_down_outlined,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

HorizontalSection(
                title: 'Your Affirmations',
                leadingContainer: Container(
                  height: AppSizes.screenHeight / 8,
                  width: AppSizes.screenWidth / 4,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                items: [
                  AffirmationAudioBox(),
                  AffirmationAudioBox(),
                  AffirmationAudioBox(), 
                  AffirmationAudioBox(),
                  AffirmationAudioBox(),
                ],
              )```

I don't have any problems with the processes with setstate, but I encounter such a problem when I want to make an animated and more stylish design.

